# Insert an IFrame into Outlook Email composed by a Macro

Tags: vba, outlook

I had a code written -

```
With objMsg
  .htmlbody = BodyStr & "<br/><br/><iframe src=""http://www.google.com""></iframe><p style=""font-family:calibri"">With Regards,<br/>" & names(1) & " " & names(0) & "</p><br/>"
  .Subject = "Mail - " & EndDateTime & ISTorPST
  .To = "email@email.com"
  .Display
End With
```

But the IFrame isnt rendered. How can I ensure it is rendered?

Comment: The vast majority of email & webmail clients will not even attempt to display iframe content so unless you are targeting a specific client that you know allows iframes this is never going to work.

Comment: @AlexK. im specifically targetting Microsoft outlook only.. Nothing else

Comment: Outlook (windows) will not show iframe content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook does not support IFrames.  From [MS Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx):

> **Unsupported HTML Elements Compared with the HTML 4.01**
>   Specification
>   The following is a list of top-level HTML elements that the HTML 4.01 specification supports, but that Word 2007 does not support. Note that Word 2007 considers unsupported HTML elements to be unknown elements.
>   Word 2007 does not support:
>   - applet
>   - bdo
>   - button
>   - form
>   - **iframe**
>   - input
>   - isindex
>   - menu
>   - noframes
>   - noscript
>   - object
>   - optgroup
>   - option
>   - param
>   - q
>   - script
>   - select

That document is a little out of data (HTML 4.01!).

Desktop versions of Outlook 2007, 2010, 2013 and 2016 all use the [Word engine](https://www.howto-outlook.com/faq/wordhtml.htm) to render HTML.  Previous versions used IE.

@Alex K deserves the points for this, as he correctly answered in the OP comments.  I've added this answer so I could include the links, for completeness.